# FCM onMessageReceived does not fire when app is killed (Android Oreo)

Tags: java, android

I am working at an app that needs to open a foreground service when a FCM message is sent. My code is:
FirebaseService.class:

```
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class FirebaseService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d("From",remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Intent intt = new Intent(this,foreground.class);
        startActivity(intt);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        String channelId = "TT";
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                        .setContentTitle("TR")
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        Log.d("TEST","received");
        Server server = new Server();
        try {
            if(server.connect())
                Log.d("TEST","Connected");
            else
                Log.d("TEST","NOT Connected");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

But when I send a meesage it shows me another notification (not the one I create in my function) with the  message body and title that I wrote when the meesage was sent.(in my function I do not sent the title and body from the received message and I just put some random text). And my foreground class is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I had nearly the same problem and asking the user to grant

```
ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION
```

solved the problem in my case. After that, the foreground class got fired.

[Restrictions on starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)

Comment: What are you saying is for android 10+. I am working in Oreo so does not make sense. Anyways, thanks for your answer.

Comment: That's true in Oreo you do not need this permission. Are you sure it works with the context of a service? In such a case you may consider checking out this: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation